# how check if respone post jquery is empty or has error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try this:

```
$.post('blog.php',
    {   },
    function(data,status){
        if(data && data != "")
        {
            $("#readmore").before(data);
        }
        else
        {
            alert('no more text');
        }
});
```

Normally it works. but when blog.php is empty do not run `else` condition.

the content of blog.php is text.

Comment: And what's wrong with your code? What data looks like when it is 'empty'???

Comment: console log your data part and show

Comment: Use the debugger built into your browser to set a breakpoint on your `if` and look at what's in `data` when you think the post is "empty." Also, note that `if data && data != "")` is functionally equivalent to `if (data)` (with those operands, if the left-hand operand is truthy, then the right-hand operand *cannot* be falsey and so you can just leave it off).

Comment: @VishalKumarMitra: No need for stumbling about in the dark with a `console.log` torch when you can *turn the lights on*. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : Thanks for the phrase.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that `data` isn't empty if your else isn't firing, as suggested, debug using your browser and break points,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the request succeeds and *truly* returns a blank string, your check would be fine, although you don't need the second half of it. E.g.:

```
if (data) {
    // Yes it's there
} else {
    // No, it's blank
}
```

...is sufficient. But if it may have *any* whitespace, you'll need to `trim` first:

```
if (data.trim()) {
    // Yes it's there
} else {
    // No, it's blank
}
```

(Some old browsers like IE8 may not have `trim`, but you can easily shim/polyfill it.)

To handle the error case, add a `.fail` handler; for cleanliness, let's move the success handler to `.done` as well, remove the declaration of the argument we're not using, and remove the unnecessary blank object.

That gives us:

```
$.post('blog.php')
    .done(function(data){
        if (data.trim())
        {
            $("#readmore").before(data);
        }
        else
        {
            alert('no more text');
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // it failed
    });
```

Note that that assumes the `Content-Type` on the response is `text/html` or `text/plain` or similar, and so you'll get back a string. From what you've said, that's probably true.

You can always see exactly what's going on by using the debugger built into your browser:

1. Open the developer tools using the menu or F12 (on IE and some others) or Ctrl+Shift+I (Chrome and some others, I think it's Cmd+Shift+I on Mac OSX).
2. Switch to the Source tab (perhaps called Debugger on IE)
3. Find your code, there's usually some way to browse the loaded scripts.
4. Click in the left-hand gutter (next to the line number) of the first line in your `done` handler and a red mark or bar should appear, which means there's a *breakpoint* there that will stop your code. Do the same for the first line inside your `fail` handler.
5. Trigger the post operation. One of your breakpoints should get hit, causing execution to stop at that point.
6. If it's in the `done` handler, hover your mouse over `data` to see **exactly** what's in it (or switch to the "Console" tab, type `data`, and press enter, and it will show you the content of the `data` argument).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. you'r right. I printed the content with exit(' ') and also return false for empty state in blog.php and now it works.